# Hebrew on mobile web site

Tags: html, utf-8, hebrew

I am trying to build a basic web page for mobile devices, on my pc Chrome browser I see "???? ???? ???" every where Hebrew written. Here is my code:

```
<?php

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="he">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="he" />
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="PHPEclipse 1.2.0" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/light_blue.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <title>מניין</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wraper" data-role="header">בדיקה בדיקה הדיקה</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using eclipse IDE for developing. Any suggestions for how to solve this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `; charset=UTF-8`  and add `<meta charset="iso-8859-8">` inside the document `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

what browser do you use?

on Chrome it works good

Comment: I also use chrome, and also on ie 9 it happens